# (Django) disable button after one click(or only submit once even clicked multiple times)

Tags: django, python-3.x

Likes field is a ManyToManyField and I want to render the post in order from most likes to least. ... order_by("-likes") didn't work and I don't see why here's the code. I'm guessing it's because it's not an integer but I can't just do ... order_by("-likes.count"), right?

views.py

```
def top_Post(request, id=None):
queryset_list = Post.objects.all().order_by("-likes")

paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10) 
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    "object_list":queryset,
    "title":"List",
}
return render(request, 'blog/top.html', context)
```

top.html

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
<div class="card border-success mb-3" style="max-width: 54rem;">
<div class="card-header bg-transparent border-success">{{ 
obj.user|truncatechars:12}} <br> <small>{{ obj.date|timesince }} ago</small> 
</div>
<div class="card-body text-success">
<h5 class="card-title">{{ obj.title |truncatechars:13 }}</h5>
<p class="card-text">{{ obj.body|truncatechars:20 }}</p>
<a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" 
role="button">Detail</a>
</div>
<div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-success"> 
{{obj.text_author|truncatechars:25 }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
body = models.TextField()
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')
text_author = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: The title and the body of your question tell completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset_list = Post.objects.all().order_by("likes").desc()
```

Comment: Do you try this solution?